# QDialog - how to close with custom button in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qdialog

**I use this code to open Dialog box but I do not know how to close it without default button**

code :

```
class MyApp (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        #### signals ####
        self.ui.action_add_contacte.triggered.connect(self.Dialog_add_contact)
        
        
    def  Dialog_add_contact(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog_add_contacte()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.ui.btn_cancel_add_contacte.clicked.connect(lambda:pass #some code need to close)
        dialog.exec_()
```

I try

```
Dialog.ui.close()
```

but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as any widget, `dialog.close()`.

`ui` is not a widget, it's helper class object, you cannot `close()` it.